# C - detect when an external circuit is closed (button push)

Tags: c

I am trying to find out if there is a way for a C console program to detect when an external circuit is closed (e.g. a button is pushed). I have searched for code examples or insight but with no luck.

I know this is easy in arduino/raspberry pi etc. but this will be part of a C console program running on windows.

Ideally the button/switch will be connected by USB or serial.
My current thoughts are to make the switch part of a HID and have it act as a keystroke but this is not my preference.

My preference would be to just close the circuit (short the usb) and have some code that registers when a usb or serial port has a voltage applied but I am not sure if that is possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since you know It is easy to do this on a Arduino or Raspberrypi, you can have a chat with them via COM port(arduino) or Ethernet (raspberrypi). And indirectly determine whether a buttons was closed. Or determine how to run windows on a raspberrypi TLDR;.

Comment: This is pretty vague and I'm not sure what you actually need help with. You've said what's not your preference but not what is. In the end it will come down to the driver support you have for the hardware.

Comment: @RetiredNinja my preference would be to just close the circuit (short the usb) and have some code that registers when a usb or serial port has a voltage applied but I am not sure if that is possible. From the answers so far it looks like I will have to implement an external hardware piece like Arduino which isn't the end of the world, but not my preference.

Comment: USB digital I/O boards, and relevant drivers etc, are easily available, (except in UK, where everything is Brexit-bound and stuck in containers endlessly circling the island).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @MartinJames, I will weigh up this vs. an arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, although you still need external hardware (for example, Arduino).

1. Via UART - With every Arduino you can communicate via UART/Serial. You will need send data from Arduino to PC when button state changes, and then listen for this data in your C app on computer.
2. Via HID - For example, Arduino Leonardo (and all other Arduinos with ATmega32U4) have USB Host feature, so you can create your own HID and send data this way, or directly via USB (without HID usage).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I will go with an arduino.

Answer (score 0):

15pol game port and 25pol parallel port are able to detect/switch signals, inputs and outputs.

The 15pol game port would be most easy to use, if you still have some.